# поиск по массиву объектов postgres

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, postgresql13

есть колонка типa `json`. в ней хранятся данные вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и я хочу сделать поиск по ключю `Ref_Key` в объекте. я пробовал делать поиск с eloquent таким образом

```php
SystemInfo::select('functionsss')->whereJsonContains('functionsss', [['Ref_Key' => '1837117a-419b-11ea-bf13-005056a43b58']])->get()
```

и пробовал делать такой прямой запрос

```sql
select * from "system_infos" where ("functionsss")::jsonb @> '[{"Ref_Key": "1837117a-419b-11ea-bf13-005056a43b58"}]'
```

но ни то ни другое не дало ожидаемый результат. погуглив так же не нашел работающего решения.

p.s. так же нужно получить оттуда все уникальные значения свойства `Ref_Key`, ну т.е. как если бы `GROUP BY` но с свойством объекта. так же не получилось. если не ответят в текущем, это будет новый вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

при записи в бд я сохранял значения этой колонки используя на массиве объектов `json_encode()`. так

```php
$systemInfo['functions'] = json_encode($functionsss)
```

а надо было так

```php
$systemInfo['functions'] = $functionsss
```

после того как поменял. значения в бд стали выглядеть так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

возможно дело было в экранировании

а прибаутку с `GROUP BY` можно добиться с помощью `DISTINCT`. я сделал это так

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (functions->>'Description', functions->>'Ref_Key') functions
FROM  (
     SELECT functions::jsonb AS si_functions_column from system_infos
   ) function_colunmn
   , jsonb_array_elements(function_colunmn.si_functions_column) WITH ORDINALITY t(functions)
ORDER  BY functions->>'Description', functions->>'Ref_Key';
```

Comment: да. я переименовал колонку